# CORS issues in MVC application 4.5 using ajax request for googleOauth

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cors

I am receiving a CROSS Origin request Blocked error, telling me that I have CORS Header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing" and "the request did not succeed".

I have followed many of the open issues here, one of them was to place these below in my web config, but I still receive the error:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
```

Here is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "ExternalLogin",
   type: "POST"
});
```

Am I missing something? Please help, I have spend almost 3hrs on this issue. 
Thank you

As of today, here are things I have added to my application to authenticate users using google OAuth, but I am still facing with the "Same Cross Origin" missing issue:

Web config (not the one in views)

```
 <system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
```

I have added the nugget package to enable CORS in my global.asx as follow

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:5630", "*", "*")
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

And this is within the AccountController ExternalLogin call

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");

            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
            if (UserId != null)
            {
                properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
            }
            context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
        }
```

I am so confused and don't know what to do now, any one to help?

Answer (score 0):

- In CORS call's both request and the response should contain the headers.
- your request part seems fine and correct,issue is that your response is not served with allow cross orgin request header for this requestor.

Comment: I have just updated my code with the changes above put I still have the same issue

Comment: Did you made sure whether the domain/resource your are trying to access accepts CORS calls?

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there, but for fun try this, modify your AJAX request to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + ExternalLogin,
    headers: {
        'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: YourData,
    success: function(data){
      console.log('success: '+ data);
    }
  });
```

Give it a shot, see if you're still getting the CORS error or if using cors-anywhere broke through;

I've also spent hours on CORS myself before discovering cors-anywhere; it saved me a lot of time, may save you some time as well. :)